# How can a simple Principal Component Analysis be made in Python using pandas and scikit-learn?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pca

I'm following an example [here](http://setosa.io/ev/principal-component-analysis/). I have some 17D food data for which I want to make a 2D principal component analysis plot:

```
import pandas as pd

df_raw = pd.DataFrame(
             [
                 ["alcoholic drinks"  ,  375,  135,  458,  475],
                 ["beverages"         ,   57,   47,   53,   73],
                 ["carcase meat"      ,  245,  267,  242,  227],
                 ["cereals"           , 1472, 1494, 1462, 1582],
                 ["cheese"            ,  105,   66,  103,  103],
                 ["confectionery"     ,   54,   41,   62,   64],
                 ["fats and oils"     ,  193,  209,  184,  235],
                 ["fish"              ,  147,   93,  122,  160],
                 ["fresh fruit"       , 1102,  674,  957, 1137],
                 ["fresh potatoes"    ,  720, 1033,  566,  874],
                 ["fresh Veg"         ,  253,  143,  171,  265],
                 ["other meat"        ,  685,  586,  750,  803],
                 ["other veg."        ,  488,  355,  418,  570],
                 ["processed potatoes",  198,  187,  220,  203],
                 ["processed veg."    ,  360,  334,  337,  365],
                 ["soft drinks"       , 1374, 1506, 1572, 1256],
                 ["sugars"            ,  156,  139,  147,  175]
             ],
             columns = [
                 "food",
                 "England",
                 "Northern Ireland",
                 "Scotland",
                 "Wales"
             ]
         )

df_raw
```

[image]

I run the the PCA fit in the following way:

```
# drop food names
df = df_raw[[column for column in df_raw.columns if column != "food"]]

# perform PCA
import sklearn.decomposition

pca = sklearn.decomposition.PCA(n_components = 2)
pca.fit(df)
```

I attempt to project the features onto principal components for the purpose of the 2D plot:

```
projection = pca.transform(df)
x = projection[:,0]
y = projection[:,1]
```

I then plot:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
sns.set(context = "paper", font = "monospace")

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.axes().set_aspect(1 / plt.axes().get_data_ratio())
plt.xlabel("PC1")
plt.ylabel("PC2")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Shit don't look right to me. I was expecting four points (and I'd love to know how to label those points). Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your data has 4 dimensions (since you excluded Food from your dataframe) and 17 examples. When you do PCA, you want to reduce the dimensions while keeping the maximum information possible. In this case you are converting the original 4 dimensions to number of components which in your case is 2. PCA doesn't change the number of observations, so you see the 17 points in your scatter plot.

I didn't get into the details of PCA because that will be a separate topic and you can find many tutorials and mathematics behind it.

Answer (score 0):

PCA is a dimensionality reduction technique.  You have 4 features (countries in this example)   and
`pca = sklearn.decomposition.PCA(n_components = 2)` is saying you want to project all of your data points onto two features.

You are not reducing the amount of data points (17 in this case)

Why are you performing a PCA? What is the goal of your analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Transpose the matrix df and it will work like the linked example.

```
df = df.T
```